# python change value of a global variable

Tags: python, variables, global

This might be a stupid question but I just want to know why and how.

I have variable `deviceConfig` (dict) declared globally in a .py file. My expected outcome: once the .py run has finished, it'll change the global variable value in the file.

I tested to print value at top of script and end of the script. After python runtime finished, the initial value and output are different. This means it works to change the value of global variable at runtime.

But when I open the .py file again after it has finished running, the value of the variable is still the same. (maybe because I hardcoded the dict value?)

```
deviceConfig = {}

deviceConfig["sw_ui"] = "0.1"

print deviceConfig #output 0.1

#this is change value function
def alterValue():

    global deviceConfig

    #change the value from 0.1 to 0.2
    deviceConfig["sw_ui"] = "0.2"


alterValue()
print deviceConfig #output 0.2 at runtime
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'But i open again the .py file after finished'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this

```
deviceConfig["sw_ui"] = "0.2"
```

you change the *runtime value* of `deviceConfig["sw_ui"]`. But changing the value of a variable at runtime does not change your Python source code. If you want such changes to persist across invocations of your program you need to store them in a configuration file.